# Spring WebFlow: Cleanup on HttpSession invalidation

Tags: servlets, spring-webflow

If I need to perform some resource cleanup (deleting temporary files) upon Flow completion, including when the `HttpSession` times out, what's the best way to do this?

`FlowExecutionListener.sessionEnding()` is called when an end-state is visited, but not when the HttpSession times out.

Is there a safe way for an `HttpSessionListener` to access to SWF scopes?

(Spring 3.0, WebFlow 2.3)

Comment: FYI, opened a Spring JIRA issue to request a new capability https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1506